# MySQL LEFT JOIN slow, no index used

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join

So we've got two tables in two databases, `db1` and `table1`, and `db2` and `table2`. However, trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` on them takes upwards of three minutes. Insane, I know.

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`table1` AS a LEFT JOIN `db2`.`table2` AS b ON a.col=b.col
```

`a` is about 14,000 rows. `b` is about 825,000 rows.

We have `col` of both `a` and `b` indexed. `col` is, in both cases, a `VARCHAR(16)` with `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.

Running an explain

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `db1`.`table1` AS a LEFT JOIN `db2`.`table2` AS b ON a.col=b.col
```

shows us that no index is being used for either table. I assume this is why the performance is so terrible.

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14174   
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    824687
```

However, I don't understand *why* this is happening or how to fix it. Joining `b` with other tables that are far larger works in seconds, and indexing is appropriately used. What is happening in this case, and what steps should I take to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting every column from every table. Varchar fields are inefficient for indexing oppose to a primary key index. Your index should be on the fields you're joining on otherwise, they are pretty useless, except for search efficiency.

```
SELECT col, col4, col5, col6 FROM `db1`.`table1` AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT col,col1, col2, col3 from `db2`.`table2` order by 1,2,3) AS b ON a.col=b.col
```

If you join on the sub-query you will only extract the columns you need which will speed up performance dramatically, as well as you create an index with your order by 1,2,3 at the end of the sub-query.

You must include the field you will be joining on in the sub-query also...

**ANSWER**

It will not make sense to use the index for your query, because you are selecting the full text column. That means that MySQL cannot use the index alone to satisfy the query.

Comment: also you can use FORCE_INDEX to specify an index to MySQL

Comment: @SamD `FORCE INDEX` did not result in the index being used.

Comment: @MirroredFate how about SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)

Comment: @Hituptony This did reduce the time to around five seconds, but there is still no index used for table `b`. You also didn't really answer my question, because regardless of the inefficiency of `VARCHAR`s for indexing *they are not actually being used at all*.

Comment: @SamD ...why are there two columns for indexes? Is one supposed to be the `primary key` and the other one `col`'s index?

Comment: it's not using your varchar index because it's inefficient. It's faster to NOT use the index you created.